# 'by mistakenly, he dropped it' is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Can I use both words 'by mistakenly' together? I feel that either I can put it as ' by mistake' or as' mistakenly' but not together.

Comment: Your question is very basic; it might be a better fit for [the English Language Learners Stack Exchange site](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If you think you may have heard someone say this, my guess is you misheard them and they actually said "But, mistakenly, ..."

Answer (score 1):

No.

Use:

> He dropped it **by mistake**.

or

> He **mistakenly** dropped Organic Chemistry.

The following would also be correct gramatically:

> **By mistakenly dropping** the required class, he jeopardized his chance to graduate.

(However, this is awkward, since it leaves the sentence ambiguous. You could ask, "So if he dropped the class *on purpose*, he would be allowed to graduate?")

Comment: Thanks for the info. My son's teacher (class 4) asked him to use these words together and there was no other way I could convince  him that it is not a correct usage!